# How do you use ssh-keys instead of a password to run a remote-kernel over ssh?

Tags: remote-access, networking, configuration

On all of the servers that I regularly interact with, I have [ssh-keys](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) setup for passwordless access via ssh. Yet, every time I attempt to start a remote-kernel over ssh, I get asked for a password despite having a [ssh-keyagent](http://www.phil.uu.nl/~xges/ssh/) up and running. What do I need to add to the kernel configuration, such as the launch command, to have it use my ssh-key?

I'm using version 8.0.4 on MacOS 10.6.8, if it makes a difference.

Comment: See this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/remote-kernel-error-mleconnect/156995#156995

Comment: @Karolis neat. I'll have to look through it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mathematica by default uses its own ssh implementation. You can see it in the dialog of the remote kernel configuration dialog in the advanced options: `` `java` -jar `mathssh` ``. As far as I know, you can safely replace that with the local ssh command (most likely `/usr/bin/ssh`). You have to select the "Advanced Options" radiobutton to do that (if you first add all the standard options, the rest of the command is already filled in correctly).

**Edit**: By default, Mathematica uses the launch command

```
`java` -jar "`mathssh`" user@hostname math -mathlink 
       -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName "`linkname`" 
       -LinkHost `ipaddress`
```

to invoke ssh, where `user` and `hostname` are filled in via text boxes above. To use the local ssh command, you need to change the above command to

```
ssh user@hostname "math -mathlink -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP 
                        -LinkName `linkname` -LinkHost `ipaddress`"
```

This appears to have one flaw, killing the remote kernel via the front-end no longer kills the processes on the remote server. So, that will have to be done by hand.

Comment: This answer looks a bit outdated - 10.3 shows `wolframssh` instead of `mathssh` as the default. Probably that doesn't change much but it would be good to check.