# Specifying the ports used by LinkCreate or LinkLaunch

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, remote-access

Whenever a `Link` is created using `LinkCreate` or `LinkLaunch` with `LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"`, Mathematica opens up two ports for communicating with the attached process. Can these be specified by the user of these functions?

I ask because it would allow me to route all communication over ssh via port-forwarding.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717211/understanding-kernel-frontend-communication-why-does-my-front-end-freeze

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use port forwarding, you'll need to know that for every MathLink connection, two different ports are used.  The full syntax for TCPIP link names looks like this:

```
LinkCreate["8000@1.2.3.4,8001@1.2.3.4", LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]
```

8000 and 8001 are the port numbers while `1.2.3.4` is your IP address.  You can pass only a single port number to `LinkCreate` as the link name: in this case it will return a `LinkObject` containing the full name and the other port will be automatically selected.

---

However, if you want to use SSH port forwarding, I strongly recommend using the [Remote Kernel Strategies](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/) package.  It will save you a lot of trouble.  For example, it will automatically forward ports for all *three* links that Mathematica needs for Front End - Kernel communication (`$ParentLink`, `` MathLink`$PreemptiveLink `` and `` MathLink`$ServiceLink ``).  The other two links are created by the kernel when the front end connects to it by executing the code in the file `SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/GetFEKernelInit.tr`.

Please see the presentation I linked to for more information on how the connection is made and why three links are needed.

Comment: Reading through the pdf now. Incidentally, it says that mathssh does do public key authentication, but my experience was [different](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/288/52). I wonder why that is so.

Comment: @rcollyer With Remote Kernel Strategies you don't need to rely on mathssh.  On Windows it uses putty.  On Unix-based systems I guess it uses whatever ssh the system has ..

Comment: I read through the shell script, and yes it uses `ssh` not `mathssh`.

Answer (score 7):

From [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingMathLinkToCommunicateBetweenMathematicaSessions.html):

```
LinkCreate["8000", LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]
```

Further down that page is shown:

> This connects to the port on frog.wolfram.com.
>
> ```
> link = LinkConnect["2981@frog.wolfram.com,2982@frog.wolfram.com", 
>          LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]
> ```

Comment: I like this answer because you deliver the source as well. That should be standard practice if you ask me.