# Launching Remote Kernels takes a lot of time

Tags: parallelization, kernel, remote-access, kernel-startup

I recently played around with establishing a remote kernel setup without using mathematica grid. To do this I use the `LaunchKernels[]` command and `ssh` to establish the connection. A call to my remote desktop (RemoteDesktop) then looks like:

```
Needs["SubKernels`LocalKernels`"]
LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine["RemoteDesktop", 
  "ssh -x -f -l username `1` math -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit >& /dev/null &", 8]]
```

Which returns the following error:

> SubKernels`Protected`kernelFlush::time: Operation LinkWrite timed out after 15.` seconds

It actually took me some time to figure out, that launching a kernel on RemoteDesktop actually takes longer than the predefined limit of 15 seconds. If I increase the limit to some way higher timespan like this:

```
Parallel`Settings`$MathLinkTimeout = 100.
```

`LaunchKernels[]` sure takes its time, but all the kernels are launched eventually.

**So I cannot help but wonder: Is this an ordinary behavior or do you think something is going wrong regarding my setup, which results in launching kernels taking more time? If so, what could be the reason?**

Further information: I am working on a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.9 and Mathematica 9.0.1. I testet remote connections to another Mac with OS X 10.8 and Mathematica 9.0.1 and a 64 Bit Linux Machine. Launching kernels took way longer than 15 seconds in each of these two scenarios.

Comment: If this helps: No, it does not always take 15 seconds.  Unfortunately I can't offer advice ... just wanted to let you know that something might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will take a closer look at what might be going wrong. Any suggestions on how to monitor the `LaunchKernel[]` process in mathematica?

Comment: Might help you: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/remote-kernel-error-mleconnect/156995#156995