# How to run Mathematica kernel on remote server?

Tags: remote-access

This might be a really stupid question, but I have no idea how to get my copy of Mathematica to run on a remote server in the cloud.

I have a Webfaction account and a copy of Mathematica installed on my computer, but I don't know how to actually set up, install and run a Mathematica kernel in the cloud.

I understand that beginners' questions are generally not well received on Stack Exchange, so just a pointer to a site or page where I could find instructions would be enough. I've tried finding some myself but have come up completely blank.

Thank you

Comment: Just install it as you would on any Linux system. Any respect in which the process differs will be Webfaction-specific and therefore not answerable by this community.

Comment: Hi Aron, I would argue that good questions are always quite welcome here as long as the problem is not answered by the few first entries of the *Mathematica* help or a quick search of the site. As @OleksandrR. pointed out, perhaps only users with a similar setup will be able to help (although adding links to documentation etc. is always good).

Comment: Are you asking about connecting to a remote kernel, while using your local front end?  Theoretically this is simple and it's described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ConnectToARemoteKernel.html).  Unfortunately if problems do come up, often they are not easy or quick to solve, at least in my experience.

Comment: Try this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/remote-kernel-error-mleconnect/156995#156995