# Mathematica remote kernel on ubuntu

Tags: kernel, remote-access, ubuntu

I want to evaluate an expression on a server where it has a kernel. I totally searched on the internet but still I am not able to connect to the remote kernel. I am looking for a *clear* and a *direct* answer. For this reason, I first clarify some points.

Suppose my username and password on the server are respectively "admin" and "123". The server address is "server.com" and the kernel is in the directory "/main/folder/" and the name of the kernel is "math". I am using ubuntu 16.04 and Mathematica 11.1.1.

My question in brief is:

> How can I configure Mathematica remote kernel on ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 3):

> Duplicating the answer from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/remote-kernel-error-mleconnect/156995#156995) to make it easier to find.

This [solution](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/321179) is tested for M11.2 for macOS client and Linux server.

1. [Create a password-less ssh login. Generated a public and private ssh key on the local machine (mac) and then copy the public key to the remote machine.](https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/)
2. [Download packages from here.](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/)
3. Copy the file `init.m` to the directory `~/.Mathematica/Kernel/` directory on the remote machine.
4. Copy the file `tunnel.sh` to the directory `~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/` on the local machine.
5. In Mathematica, go Evaluation => Kernel Configuration Options => Add.

   - Select "Advanced Options"
   - Arguments for MLOpen: 
      
     `-LinkMode Listen -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkOptions MLDontInteract -LinkHost 127.0.0.1`
   - Arguments for Launch command: 
      `` "/Users/Account/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/tunnel.sh" user@remote.machine:port "wolfram" "`linkname`" ``
   - where `Account` must be your user name on the macOS.
   - where `user` by login in remote machine;
   - where `remote.machine` by ip address of remote machine;
   - where `port` by ssh port of remote machine.
   - Also make sure that `wolfram` command is available on the remote machine.
6. Be patient, since establishing connections can take time. You can find a log file at `~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/`

Comment: For anyone else unable to extract the zip file containing `tunnel.sh`, you can find it [here](https://github.com/sakra/Tunnel/blob/master/scripts/tunnel.sh). Note though I couldn't get it working, though direct `ssh` in the Launch command worked

Comment: Those unable to resolve the `wolfram` command on the server - you can view the kernel location by evaluating `$CommandLine` in a server notebook. Mine was called `WolframKernel`