# Using a Remote Kernel

Tags: external-calls, mac-os-x, remote-access

I'm trying to connect the front end on Mac OS (version 13.0) use a remote (also 13.0) kernel running on an Ubuntu machine. I've followed the basic steps here (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ConnectToARemoteKernel.html), but ended up with a similar issue as described in [this post [1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/remote-kernel-error-mleconnect).
The error is

```
The kernel voyager failed to connect to the front end. (Error = MLECONNECT). You should try running the kernel connection outside the front end.
```

In [[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/remote-kernel-error-mleconnect) they mention using this [3rd party wolfram library](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/) which seems like not a very elegant solution since Mathematica is apparently designed to be used out of the box for remote dev. Since [[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/remote-kernel-error-mleconnect) was written almost 9 years ago I'm wondering if there is a simpler/modern solution for remote dev in WL.

Thanks

Edit:

any ideas how to set up the remote kernel to use the default ssh key instead of asking for authentication every time?

Comment: I would suggest to use some kind of vnc (for example tigerVNC https://tigervnc.org/ ). Then simply run vnc server in ubuntu, connect to it from MAC and feel like working with ubuntu desktop. This model have many benefits. For example, your can disconnect from remote computer at any time and connect again without breaking computations, etc.

Comment: If you have access to a license for [*Wolfram Lightweight Grid Manager*](https://www.wolfram.com/lightweight-grid-manager/), that would be an easy to implement and quite a robust solution.

Comment: @rhermans I have wolfram desktop on my mac, but am using the free wolfram engine on my server

Comment: Don't do this, instead, launch a remote desktop with VNC

Comment: @user5601 any reason why? I don't have root access to my machine so would prefer a simple ssh solution

Comment: @user2757771 they never matured the ssh connection tech, virtually impossible to use

Comment: @user5601 Ok I see, my solution for now is to just use the Wolfram Language for the Jupyter plugin since I'm only running the free wolfram engine on the remote. I get that the technology is not mature, but it seems like it should work in theory, I'm sure I had the ssh tunnel working properly but still couldn't get anything to work. Would be nice if WFR fixed this issue.

Comment: @user2757771 please hound WRI tech support about this, maybe they will improve it!