# How to connect to EC2?

Tags: kernel, remote-access, configuration

I have Mathematica 10.2 installed on an Ubuntu 14 machine in Amazon web services's elastic computer cloud. I have dido access and I'm connected to the instance though ssh on the terminal.

I have an empty Mathematica 10.2 notebook (running locally on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3) and I would like set the local notebook to use a remote kernel.

Remote connection info:
 - Username: ubuntu
 - Hostname: xxxxxxxxx
 - Password: /my/local/path/to/key.pem
 - Mathematica path: set to installation defaults (/usr/local/bin)

I've been stuck on this for days, and have read every SE post relating to remote configurations! I can't figure out ***how to properly launch the remote kernel and then connect my local front-end to a that remote kernel***

Note: I have yet to find any documentation relating to *remote kernels whose machine are accessed with PEM keyfiles*.

Comment: Have you tried using ssh [directly](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291/52)?

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks, yes I tried that answer to no avail.

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing I'd be happy to, shall we do a chat session?

Comment: M.R. I wonder if you were able to solve your problem. If so, could you share what worked in an answer?

Comment: @MarcoB Sadly still no luck!

Comment: @M.R. Hi have you figured out a way to connect with 11.3? I am also seeing the MLCONNECT error.

Comment: @user21 I have not

Comment: @M.R. thanks for letting me know. This is such a mess.

Answer (score 3):

sorry for answering so late but i just saw the question. Actually it is quite simple. 
Just go to evaluation>kernel configuration options
add a new kernel
and fill like this: 
[image]

replacing path/to/your/perm/key, yourec2user and your.ec2.address with your information.

notice that we are using macs native ssh instead of mathematica's java ssh. the -i option is used to connect with a perm key.

make sure that your ports are open in your ec2 instance. actually mathematica just picks up a random? port  so just for testing open all of them. If that works, then you can replace `linkname` with openPort1@yourIp,openPort2@yourIP

Notice that your ip must be public in order for this to work. Mathematica at ec2 needs to know how to connect back to your end. If you don have a public ip, you can install openvpn at ec2 an connect to it previously to connecting to mathematica

Comment: This isn't working for me.

Comment: I followed all your instructions but I'm still getting this: "The kernel ssd failed to connect to the front end. (Error = MLECONNECT). You should try running the kernel connection outside the front end."

Comment: just to check... did you open al the ports at your ec instance ?

Comment: @M.R. did you get this to work eventually? is it possible?

Comment: I did @ConorCosnett and it worked well, but v11.1 broke it, using a remote kernel with a local front end is no longer possible :(

Answer (score 1):

**Still doesn't work in v11.2:**

This is a response to elbOlita:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure so I have to ask – you do realize that "Basic options" is grayed out in elbOlita's answer, i.e. not used, yes? Because this is in no way a comment elbOlita's solution, which is completely different.

Comment: yes, I just pasted the wrong screenshot